# mongodb binary regex pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, binary, pymongo, bson

Can i use regex find in pymongo on fields created with bson.binary.Binary?

I have some objects created with `collection.insert_one({"data": bson.binary.Binary(some_bin_data)})`.

I'm trying `collection.find({"data": {"$regex": str(rg)}})`, `collection.find({"data": {"$regex": bson.regex.Regex(rg)}})` and `collection.find({"data": {"$regex": re.compile(rg)}})` to filter objects with a regex but they don't work.

I can't find nothing about it in the pymongo docs.

Alternatively, there is another way to store binary data in a mongodb field and use regex?

Comment: What do you want to match against?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB Regex only supports string values

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Confirmed by the regex matching code in the mongod server.  Note in the link below that regex only attempts to match against strings and symbols.  Any other type, the response is hardcoded to `false` on line 274

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/b5291b87ab3350bff9bd9ef4464a63dcda81ac21/src/mongo/db/matcher/expression_leaf.cpp#L262-L274

Furthermore

there are only 4 query operations you can do on queries against binary types

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-bitwise/

As an alternative:

You could *(probably a very bad idea)* ascii armor (in python do `<bytes>.decode("hex")` which will give you a UTF-8 string).  Put the UTF-8 string into the database.  You'll need to cleverly craft your new regex to match against the ascii-arored string rather than the binary data itself.

Again, matching an arbitrary regex against Binary data *that should be put in GridFS anywa*y is abusing MongoDB in a way it is ill-suited to be used.